# Saved image is overriding the previous image in sd card android

Tags: android, image, download, android-sdcard

In my application i am allowing the user to download number of images from Url links and storing them in SD card. Every time the new image downloaded is overriding the previous image with same name. So finally i am having only one image in SD card that is downloaded at the last.

```
     try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            URLConnection connection = (URLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

            String filename;
            Date date = new Date(0);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            filename = sdf.format(date);
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + filename + ".jpg");

            try {
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),filename,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // 5
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            return null;
        }
```

I need help in storing all images that i have downloaded.

Comment: You are giving same name to the image so this problem occurred . use random generator to give the name of image .

Comment: please suggest me how to do?.

Comment: simple generate the filename using time stamp.

Comment: How do the url's look? They will contain the image name? Then use that name!

Comment: `file.createNewFile();`. Remove that statement. The file will be created by the new FileOutputStream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    try this:

         Random generator = new Random();
         int n = 10000;
         n = generator.nextInt(n);
         filename = sdf.format(date+ n);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            getString(R.string.images));
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(mediaStorageDir, fname);
```